# how to set a default value for angular ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2, ui-select

**Question :**

how to set default value to the angular ui-select

drop down values are fetched from object and object wont be having default value.

and ui-select should set the default value in Frontend.

eg:

drop down values are as follows

**1 -all fruits**
*2 -apple
3 -banana 
4 -water melon*

value from 2 to 4 are derived from object sent from server.but Frontend need to set default value ie 1 - all fruits

Referring to the below example set via ui-select2 how to migrate this in ui-select?

```
<select ng-model="fID" class="select"  ui-select2 data-placeholder="select fruit">
            <option value="">All fruits</option>
            <option ng-repeat="f in frits value="{{f.fID}}">{{f.name}}</option>
        </select>

<ui-select theme="select2" ng-model="fruits.selected">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="select please" allow-clear="false">                    {{$select.selected.name}}
</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="f in fruits | filter:$select.search">
                <div ng-bind-html="f.name | highlight: $select.search:'underline'"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
Link :angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: you can set the default/initial value in your controller

Comment: ng-init will set a default value: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 2):

you didnt use an id or something like that for option value so ui-select compares object address to understand if it is selected.

```
var p1 = { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 };
  $scope.person = {selected: p1};
  $scope.people = [
    p1,
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43 },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 }
  ];
```

change plunker like this and you will have a default selected value.

to set the default value on view you can use ng-init and set first object as selected

Comment: also we can set  $scope.person.selected = p1 ;

Comment: i didn't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: I didn't get it either, you only showed what to do on the backend but not what should be done on the directive itself.

Comment: i'll create plunkr today for this @AqibMumtaz

Answer (score 0):

I found this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/28/

Angular code:

```
<a href="#" editable-select="user.status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
    {{ showStatus() }}
  </a>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.user = {
    status: 2
  }; 

  $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ]; 

  $scope.showStatus = function() {
    var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: $scope.user.status});
    return ($scope.user.status && selected.length) ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi Aqib, please try to include code snippet into your answer

Comment: Stackoverflow is creating trouble while attaching url

Comment: Yes it is the case if you include one line answer with link, now you can update your link in appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add the following code:

```
 $scope.fruits.selected = {name: 'All fruits'};
```

The above will set the default selected value to the drop down.